# Display and hide elements depending on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a search bar functionality for my app, when there is no results from the search, I need to display `Your search criteria is invalid` or something relate it.

I have this to display the results

```
        {!!this.state.value.length &&
          <div>
            {match}                
          </div>
        }
```

and I am trying to do something like

```
        {(!this.state.result.length && !!this.state.value.length) &&
            <Paper>Your search criteria is invalid</Paper>            
        }
```

but in this second case, the message still shown when there is results.

I am doing it that way because if I do `if else`, I get an error

in this case, `this.state.value` is what you type in the search bar, and `this.state.result` is the result of the search

so, what is the best technique ?

here is the full portion of code

**UPDATE**

```
class UniversalSearch extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {value : '', result: ''};
  } 

  render () {
    let searchVal = this._matchPeople(this.state.value),
        match = Object.keys(searchVal).map(function(key) {
          return <div className="threeColumn"><Paper><div className="maxHeight"><h3>{key}</h3><p>{searchVal[key]}</p></div></Paper></div>;
        }),
        searchResult = this.state.result ? match : (<Paper>Your search criteria is invalid</Paper>);
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Column>
            <TextField onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)} 
                    fullWidth={true} floatingLabelText="Universal Search" 
                    onKeyUp={this._changeInput.bind(this)} value={this.state.value} />
            {searchResult}
          </Column>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }

  _matchPeople = (input) => {
    let reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
    let filteredObj = { };
    Object.keys(falsyData).forEach(function(key) {
        if(key.match(reg)){
           filteredObj[key] = falsyData[key];
        }
    });
    return filteredObj;
  }

  _changeInput = (val) => {
    let autoCompleteResult = this._matchPeople(this.state.value);    
    if (autoCompleteResult.length) {
      this.setState({result: autoCompleteResult.join(' ')});
    };
  }

  _onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```jsx
render() {

  let searchResult = this.state.result ? match : (<Paper>Your search criteria is invalid</Paper>)

  return (
    <Column>
      <TextField onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
                 onKeyUp={this._changeInput.bind(this)} value={this.state.value} />

      { searchResult }
    </Column>
  );
}
```

---

**Edit:**

[Here is a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvLc0ro0/) with the solution I suggested
Try changing the state and see what happens to the `{ searchResult }`

Comment: nope, look at the update. Actually with this way is not showing up the results.

Comment: any chance you could make it a JSFiddle so I can play with it?